# Can I use the File connector in Mule Cloudhub for FTPS

Tags: mule, cloudhub

Is there a way to configure a File connector for use in cloudhub, specifically related to reading in a file over FTPS and putting it into a file before beginning the actual processing of the contents?

**Clarification**:
I'm in cloudhub, which does not provide a filesystem in the same sense that a local/on-prem Mule setup has. One standard practice when dealing with streams (FTPS or similar) in order to avoid processing over the open stream is to take the incoming stream and use the File connector (outbound in this case) to put the inbound stream into a file, and then use that file for your flow process. How is this managed in CloudHub?

Comment: Did you get an answer/solution for this one ?

Comment: @Sudarshan, I do not feel the question has been answered. Any experience with this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

File Connector is to read files from paths specified on the server. They cannot be used to read from remote servers.

I case you want to have a File to start your flow with try the following.

```
<flow name="ftp_reader_flow">
    <ftp: inbound>   Read from the remote directory
    ...
    <file:outbound>  to a local directory
</flow>

<flow name="actual_processing_flow">
    <file:inbound>  read from the local directory.
    ... Continue with the processing
    .....
</flow>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: You are correct, but maybe my question is not clear. I'm in cloudhub, which does not provide a filesystem in the same sense that a local/on-prem Mule setup has. One standard practice when dealing with streams (FTPS or similar) in order to avoid processing over the stream is to take the incoming stream and use the File connector (outbound in this case) and then use that file for your flow process. How is this managed in CloudHub?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the connector for temporary data with the tmp directory.

From the [MuleSoft Documentation](https://docs.mulesoft.com/runtime-manager/cloudhub-and-mule#disk-persistence):

> Disk Persistence
>
> CloudHub does not guarantee that writing to disk survives hardware
>   failures. Instead, you must use an external storage mechanism to store
>   information. For small amounts of data, you can use the Object Store.
>   For applications that have large data storage requirements, we
>   recommend use of a cloud service such as Amazon S3. For temporary
>   storage, the **File connector is still available and can be used with
>   the /tmp directory.**

Answer (score 1):

You can use **File Connector in CloudHub** as well, But Make sure your are reading or writing  the file from classpath **-src/main/resource** or any folder from project classpath only.